# What is the memory utilization for the "import" and "from import" scenarios in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the memory utilization in the following module import cases:
Let there be a module called `myfile.py` containing

```
    //myfile.py
    var  = 'Hello World'
```

Case 1:

```
    import myfile
    myfile.title
```

Case 2:

```
    from my file import title
    title
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's essentially identical. In both cases, the entire `myfile` module needs to be loaded, no matter what parts you use. Neither version will create unnecessary copies, too, so if `myfile.title` is something huge, neither version will fill your memory with copies of `myfile.title`.

Comment: So both the cases copy the whole module into the file that is importing?

Comment: @user2961121: Neither case makes a copy. No matter how many modules import `myfile` within a single program, only one `myfile` module will be loaded for all modules to share.

Comment: Ok, then what is the performance implication of qualifying the module name with attribute name to fetch it (Case 1) and directly fetching it (Case 2)?

I am sorry if the questions are stupid, am a novice :(

Comment: @user2961121: Essentially none. It is very slightly faster to refer to `title` than `myfile.title`, but almost never by enough to make a meaningful difference.

Answer (score 0):

Importing the module doesn't waste anything; the module is always fully imported (into the `myfile.modules` mapping), so whether you use `import myfile` or `from myfile import title` makes no odds.

The only difference between the two statements is what name is bound; `import myfile` binds the name `myfile` to the module (so `myfile -> myfile.modules['myfile']`), while from `myfile import title` binds a different name, title, pointing straight at the attribute contained inside of the module (so `title -> myfile.modules['myfile'].title`). The rest of the `myfile` module is still there, whether you use anything else from the module or not.

There is also no performance difference between the two approaches. Yes, `myfile.title` has to look up two things; it has to look up `myfile` in your global namespace (finds the module), then look up the attribute title. And yes, by using `from myfile import title` you can skip the attribute lookup, since you already have a direct reference to the attribute. But the import statement still has to do that work, it looks up the same attribute when importing, and you'll only ever need to use title once. If you had to use title thousands of times in a loop it could perhaps make a difference, but in this specific case it really does not.

The choice between one or the other then, should be based on coding style instead.

In a large module, I'd certainly use `import myfile`; code documentation matters, and using `myfile.title` somewhere in a large module makes it much clearer what you are referring to than just title ever would.

If the only place you use title is in a '**main**' block to call a `main()` function, by all means use `from myfile import title` if you feel happier about that:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from myfile import title
    main(title)
```

I'd still use `import myfile` there myself. All things being equal (and they are, exactly, in terms of performance and number of characters used to write it), that is just easier on the eye for me.

If you are importing something else altogether, then perhaps performance comes into play. But only if you use a specific name in a module many times over, in a critical loop for example. But then creating a local name (within a function) is going to be faster still:

```
import myfile

def title():
    localname = somemodule.somefunctionorother
    while test:
        # huge, critical loop
        foo = localname(bar)
```

Comment: Thank you for such splendid elaboration & explanation!

Comment: Could you please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965009/does-reloading-a-module-changes-the-names-in-the-module-previously-imported-relo

Thank you!

Comment: @user2961121 - I added an answer with more detail and examples.