# Does reloading a module changes the names in the module previously imported/reloaded?

Tags: python

I have a module named `myfile.py`

```
    //myfile.py
    msg = 'Hello World'
```

Then I import it: `import myfile`

Then I make some modifications, such as:

```
    //myfile.py (updated)
    a = 'Some text'
    b = 'Some other text'
```

Then I call the reload function:

```
    from imp import reload
    reload(myfile)
```

Now when I run: `dir(myfile)`
its showing the names from the current module reload as well as the previous (all other previous import/reloads)

Does this mean "all" the names (even names omitted after updating) are available separately for outside world when the module is imported/reloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`imp.reload` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/imp.html#imp.reload):

> When a module is reloaded, **its dictionary (containing the module’s global variables) is retained**. Redefinitions of names will override the old definitions, so this is generally not a problem. If the new version of a module does not define a name that was defined by the old version, **the old definition remains**.

The module is not wiped before the reload. The module's new code is executed with all old variable bindings still present. Any names the new code defines replace the old bindings, but anything the new version doesn't define retains its old value. [This also applies in Python 2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload).

Comment: I'm wondering why the docs are not written in the docstrings so that we can access them just by typing `help(imp.reload)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use Python's built-in function [reload](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload). From the docs:

> When reload(module) is executed:
>
> - Python modules’ code is recompiled and the module-level code    re-executed, defining a new set of objects which are bound to names
>     in the module’s dictionary. The init function of extension modules is 
>     not called a second time.
> - As with all other objects in Python the old objects are only    reclaimed after their reference counts drop to zero.
> - The names in the module namespace are updated to point to any new or    changed objects.
> - Other references to the old objects (such as names external to the    module) are not rebound to refer to the new objects and must be
>     updated in each namespace where they occur if that is desired.

Here is an example:

First, we create a file that defines a variable `msg` and a method to print it.

```
// myfile.py
msg = 'Hello World'
def x():
    print msg

// run from the shell
shell1$ python
>>> import myfile
>>> myfile.x()
Hello World
```

Now we modify the file, removing variable `msg` and adding `a` and `b` variables (without exiting the current Python REPL).

```
// myfile.py - updated
a = 'Some text'
b = 'Some other text'
def x():
    print '%s: %s' % (a, b)

// run from the same python session
>>> reload(myfile)
<module 'myfile' from 'myfile.pyc'>
>>> myfile.x()
Some text: Some other text
```

This is useful if you have edited the module source file using an external editor and want to try out the new version without leaving the Python interpreter.

One final note: `reload(myfile)` only reloads the specified modules. The module's (myfile) imports must be individually reloaded. Also, any objects that refer to anything in the module (like an instance whose class is defined in the module) will continue to use the previously loaded value.